# Explanation on how inversions work with merge sort

Tags: java, mergesort

my code currently works just fine, but my trouble is understand why it works. Why are certain parameters the way they need to be and why do certain have to to happen. I tried two other solutions and this seems to be the only working one.

```
public static int invCounter(int[] ranking)
{
    int[] b   = new int[ranking.length];
    int[] aux = new int[ranking.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ranking.length; i++)
        b[i] = ranking[i];
    int inversions = mergeSortInv(ranking, b, aux, 0, ranking.length - 1);
    return inversions;
}
private static int mergeInv(int[] a, int[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int inversions = 0;

    // copy to aux[]
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        aux[k] = a[k]; 
    }

    // merge back to a[]
    int i = lo, j = mid+1;
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        if      (i > mid)           a[k] = aux[j++];
        else if (j > hi)            a[k] = aux[i++];
        else if (aux[j] < aux[i]) { a[k] = aux[j++]; inversions += (mid - i + 1); }
        else                        a[k] = aux[i++];
    }
    return inversions;
}
private static int  mergeSortInv(int[] a, int[] b, int[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
    int inversions = 0;
    if (hi <= lo) return 0;
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    inversions += mergeSortInv(a, b, aux, lo, mid);  
    inversions += mergeSortInv(a, b, aux, mid+1, hi);
    inversions += mergeInv(b, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    return inversions;
}
```

If someone could explain why this works and how it works that would be great.

Comment: If you have written, you should know the logic and its way of working....isn't it?

Comment: You should do a dry-run over a very short list (say, 4 elements). It should clear itself up.